# How to convert clob data into multiple columns in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, split, clob

In a Oracle table, I have a clob column (TEXT) which has data like below.

```
"Employee ID: 1  
Hire Date: 24-Oct-2013
Name: XXXXX
Department: IT

Employee ID : 2
Name : YYYYY
Hire Date : 20-May-2014
Department: ITIS


Hire Date: 17-May-2017
Department:SMO
Name: ZZZZZ
Employee ID: 3"
```

The above CLOB data needs to be converted into multiple columns like below

```
Employee_ID   Hire_Date       Name       Department
----------------------------------------------------
1             24-Oct-2013     XXXXX      IT
2             20-May-2014     YYYYY      ITIS
3             17-May-2017     ZZZZZ      SMO
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: It's probably not in your power to change this, but Oracle has fantastic support for XML and, since 12c, pretty good support for JSON. Pretending free text is structured data is just bad architecture. I mean, the attributes aren't even in the same order.

Comment: So what is the so-called structure here? Are the attributes the same in each clob? Is one attribute per row guaranteed? Does each so-called record have the same number and name attributes? Or do you need to rely on blank lines to identify "records"? Are those framing `"` part of the text?

Comment: Yes, there will be one attribute per row and the attribute names will remain same. Yes, between records there will be more than one new line character. `"` are not part of text.

Comment: Like the other comments said: not even the order of the attributes is maintained. So, you'll have to use some Pl/sql to parse all that text, and then send it to the table.

Answer (score 0):

Code below is getting data from your string and insert column to `temporary` `table`, if you don't need `temperory table` you can use logic of getting data from string as you want

First create `temperory` table `Employeeinfo` like this

```
create global temporary table EmployeeInfo
(
  EmployeeID           varchar2(15),
  HireDate             varchar2(15),
  Name                 varchar2(100),
  Department           varchar2(10)
)
on commit preserve rows;
```

Second use this code(this is `pl/sql test script`)

```
declare

lv_string varchar2(4000) := 'Employee ID: 1  
Hire Date: 24-Oct-2013
Name: XXXXX
Department: IT

Employee ID : 2
Name : YYYYY
Hire Date : 20-May-2014
Department: ITIS


Hire Date: 17-May-2017
Department:SMO
Name: ZZZZZ
Employee ID: 3';

   lv_Token varchar2(4000);
   lv_Part varchar2(4000);
   lv_FirstPart varchar2(4000);
   lv_SecondPart varchar2(4000);
   li pls_integer := 0;
   lv_EmployeeID varchar2(15);
   lv_HireDate varchar2(15);
   lv_Name varchar2(100);
   lv_Department varchar2(10);
   function v_Partition(av_source long, av_separator varchar2,
                           ai_nth pls_integer) return varchar2 is
      li_Sep pls_integer := length(av_Separator);
      li_Begin pls_integer := 1 - li_Sep;
      li_End pls_integer;
      lv_Output long;
   begin
      li_End := instr(av_source, av_separator, 1, ai_nth);
      if ai_Nth > 1 then
         li_Begin := instr(av_source, av_separator, 1, ai_nth - 1);
         if li_Begin = 0 then
            return null;
         end if;
      end if;
      if li_End > 0 then
         lv_Output := substr(av_Source, li_Begin + li_Sep,
                             li_End - li_Begin - li_Sep);
      elsif length(av_Source) >= li_Begin + li_Sep then
         lv_Output := substr(av_Source, li_Begin + li_Sep,
                             length(av_Source) - li_Begin);
      end if;
      return lv_Output;
   end;

   function v_Token(av_source in out nocopy varchar2, av_separator varchar2)
      return varchar2 is
      lv_token varchar2(4000);
      li_pos pls_integer;
   begin
      li_pos := instr(av_source, av_separator, 1, 1);
      if li_pos > 0 then
         lv_token := rtrim(substr(av_source, 1, li_pos - 1));
         av_source := substr(av_source, li_pos + length(av_separator));
      else
         lv_token := rtrim(av_source);
         av_source := '';
      end if;
      if av_Separator = ' ' then
         av_Source := trim(av_Source);
      end if;
      return lv_token;
   end;
begin
   while lv_string is not null loop
      lv_Token := v_Token(lv_string, chr(10));
      if lv_Token is not null then
         li := li + 1;
         lv_FirstPart := trim(v_Partition(lv_Token, ':', 1));
         put(lv_FirstPart);
         lv_SecondPart := trim(v_Partition(lv_Token, ':', 2));
         if lv_FirstPart like '%Employee ID%' then
            lv_EmployeeID := lv_SecondPart;
         elsif lv_FirstPart like '%Hire Date%' then
            lv_HireDate := lv_SecondPart;
         elsif lv_FirstPart like '%Name%' then
            lv_Name := lv_SecondPart;
         elsif lv_FirstPart like '%Department%' then
            lv_Department := lv_SecondPart;
         end if;
         if li = 4 then
            insert into EmployeeInfo
            values
               (lv_EmployeeID, lv_HireDate, lv_Name, lv_Department);
            li := 0;
         end if;
      end if;
   end loop;


   --select * from EmployeeInfo; -- you can select from table
end;
```